# How can I make the map background transparent in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in which there is a) Lat b) Long c) Variable.

The variable has a range from 0-1.

I need two plots with variable plotted from 0-1 and 0.75-1 *in the same color scale*.

I am using this code:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon( data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),size=0.2, fill="white",colour="black")+
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=col,y=row,color=m))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Wind",colours = myPalette(10), limits=c(0.75,1))+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(line = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = c(.93,.20),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#854440"))+
  ggsave("test123456.png",width=6, height=4,dpi=100)
```

But I am getting this map for variable = 0.75-1. How can I make the grey background as white. And keep the state boundaries as black and in the foreground?

[image]

Comment: You seem to be using a bunch of points + geom_polygon to draw a US map (look at the NE and your strange little tail near New Mexico). Try using `ggmap` instead?

Comment: Could you please give an example suitable for me? I haven't used ggmap before.

Comment: ggmap looks fancy. All I need is a background border map....

Comment: `g = get_map("United States", zoom = 3, color = "bw",
            maptype = "roadmap",
            source = "google"); ggmap(g) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-125, -68)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 49))` Mess with the `maptype` and `source` to find a style you like.